# Difference between Producer Consumer and Sleeping Barber

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, race-condition

I'm learning synchronization problems and read about [Producer Consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) and [Sleeping Barber problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem).

I found that Producer Consumer problem is very similar with Sleeping Barber problem. Frankly I cannot found the difference between them.

Let me say...
When the producer makes a product, he add it into the queue; when a customer arrived at the barber shop, he goes to the waiting room.
Of course, the customer goes to the barber and wake him up if he is sleeping. And it seems similar in Product Consumer problem. The consumer may sleep if the queue is empty, and someone should wake him up when a new product is added to the queue.

When the queue is full, the producer should not make more product and so he has better sleep. When the consumer consumes a product from the queue and there is a place in the queue, the producer should wake up (or should be waked up by someone) to work.
I think this is similar in Sleeping Barber problem. When the waiting room is full, the newly arrived customer could wait the place in waiting room. When someone in the waiting room goes to barber, the customer of outside could enter the waiting room. (Sure, the customer could just go back home if there is no empty chair in the waiting room, but I don't think it is a big difference)

I think the implementations to solve the both problems are similar. Among various versions of the implementations, I saw the implementation using two semaphores and a mutex. Two semaphores are used to wake sleeping actors, and a mutex is used to prevent a corruption of data area by concurrent access.
I believe this solution could solve the both of problems. So I feels there is no difference between Producer Consumer problem and Sleeping Barber problem.

Comment: has my answer resolved your issue or you have any further questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Producer-Consumer problem is about that producer and consumer have different `throughputs`, so in the case of Producer producing tasks faster then Consumer executes them, then size of the queue with tasks between them will grow, thus will grow time for task from the moment it arrived in a queue and the moment Consumer takes it from the queue, and eventually you will be out of memory.

Sleeping barber problem is about `race conditions`. Imagine you have the same Producer generating tasks(people coming to barbershop) and Consumer(barber). In case not to do `busy waiting` your Consumer sleeps when there are no more tasks in the queue, so when a new task arrives it first notifies Consumer that it shouldn't sleep. So now imagine a case, when you Consumer currently is executing task `A`, and task `B` arrives, it sees that Consumer is working and will just go to the queue, but its not an `atomic` operation, so between this check(that Consumer is busy) and adding itself to the queue, Consumer can already finish task `A` and check the queue, see nothing(as `B` is still not added), and go to sleep, however `B` doesn't know about that and will wait till eventually another task `C` will come and awake Consumer.

I hope that shows that these problems are different and they have many different ways of solving them(you can easily google some ways to solve them).

For example in java you can use `BlockingQueue` to solve sleeping barber problem, so basically queue itself will awake your Producer in case there are new tasks to be executed.

One way to solve Producer-Consumer problem, is also to use `BlockingQueue` with fixed size, so when the `queue`is full, Producer will be `blocked`, when it will try to add more tasks, till there are more free space in a queue.

These problems are different, and some solutions solve just one of them, not the both. For example, for consumer-producer problem, apart from sleeping, depending on your requirements, there are other strategies:

- when the queue is full just discard new tasks producer creates. This can seem stupid and inefficient, however in a real world this approach sometimes used when you don't have a requirement to execute all produced task. A rather simple example can be that you have a producer which creates some tasks, but these tasks have timeouts and timeouts are set by some thirdparty data provider, so time starts even before you consumer actually created a task, so sleeping is not an option, and if the queue is full then its unlikely that you will do this task in time, and if you will increase the queue, not only this task would fail, but then next tasks will fail with timeouts too, and what eventually would happen - there would be no tasks which are executed in time. So you choice is to discard some new tasks, so that at some point, you can add them again and they will be executed in time. Its a real world example from quotes with rates which banks send for trading.
- the other option to solve this consumer-producer problem is to use so named `reactive streams` which is from Reactive programming. Simply, its when your consumer actually tells your producer information about its throughput. It can be number of tasks he is ready to consume at the moment, or number of tasks per second. For example, you can take a look at this [implementation](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#asynchronous-vs-synchronous-processing) or this [article](https://blog.redelastic.com/a-journey-into-reactive-streams-5ee2a9cd7e29)

These two approaches solve consumer producer problem, but they are not solve sleeping barber problem, as they don't specifically say anything about producer communication to the tasks queue.

I think you got sleeping barber problem wrong, as its not about waiting room(queue) being full, but being empty. The problem is that in case waiting room is empty and barber is busy with someone else, without some synchronization you can find yourself in a wrong state.(In consumer-producer problem you are always in a right state). Particularly new customer arrives, sees barber is busy and goes to waiting room, imagine, that this waiting room is far away, then it would take some time to get there, and while he is walking to this room, barber has already finished his work, and used a video camera to check if somebody waiting in this room, but there is nobody there at the moment, as you are still going, so barber goes asleep, and you reach waiting room and sit there, forever, if no other customer will come and wake up a barber.

There are also some other ways to solve this problem. However the most common is indeed using `BlockingQueue`. However it may seem to you that `BlockingQueue` always solves both problems, but its right only for fixed size `BlockingQueue`. You can as well have for example blocking queue without any capacity limitation(except your heap size obviously), e.g. `LinkedBlockingQueue`, then producer will never sleep, as the queue would just increase its capacity when needed. Its also widely used approach. Because sometimes you couldn't stop your producer, as it may be some remote thirdparty system, which never stops and just produces you new tasks, and you need to consume all of them, and you obviously couldn't say to it to stop, as there could be other clients listening to this data, and they don't want to stop when just one client is not as fast as the others. So you would need then to use queue without fixed size, so we will have sleeping barber problem solved by blocking queue, but we can still have problem with throughput, meaning consumer-producer problem. To solve it as well we can create some observer thread, which will sometimes check current size of the queue, if at some point it sees that queue size has increased significantly it can for example create another consumer for this queue, or notify developers that there is a problem, or do some other things. However this observer doesn't help us to solve sleeping barber problem at all.

I need to mention, that these are not the only ways of solving these problems, and they can have their advantages and disadvantages.

I tried to highlight words you can google to understand them completely.

Comment: Thank you. I read your answer. I think different throughputs and race conditions are not a difference. The both problems are about multi-threading (or multi-processing) and we will always face with the stuff of different throughputs and race conditions. I edited my question to say why I think the both problems are similar.

Comment: @YoungbaeJeon I updated my answer to your qeuestion. Also it seems to me that may you you misunderstood sleeping barber problem, as your example about this problem is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said, I think I have misunderstood about the problems. And it's a awesome that Reactive Programming could be an option to Producer Consumer problem. I've known about it a little, and I've just thought that it is mainly for manipulating UI event stream. I've got an idea that I can use the Reactive model for my project. I'd like to say thank you again.